# Network state change listener

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-wifi, android-trafficstats

I need to listen to change (connect/disconnect) of a network (mobile data in particular). I know the method using broadcast receiver and ConnectivityManager to know the type of connection.

But, in a broadcast receiver, an intent is received after the connection switches to the new network while I want to listen to the network which is being disconnected.

Why I want to do this?

I want to get the data stats for mobile data that is to say how much data has been transferred and received over 2g/3g/4g/LTE. I am using TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes() to get the data received but opposite to what the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html#getMobileRxBytes()) states this method returns zero when you are not connected to mobile data. Not only myself but many have have faced this [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78924#makechanges) as you can see here.

I know there is a workaround looking at the apps on Play Store giving the amount of data used on a daily basis.

Also, if I record data used for each second when the user is connected to Mobile data then I think it will not be too good for the battery.

Please, help me address this issue.

Thank You

Comment: Seriously? Not even a single reply.